# Is there a way to suppress error messages for specific C# types in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, enums, suppress-warnings

In Visual Studio 2019 I am working on code style settings and want the error message CS1591 to show up as a warning whenever the XML comment for a publicly visible type or member is missing.

CS1591: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1591

However, I do not want this warning to show up for Enumerables.
Is there a way to suppress this message for/in Enumerables?

The code style is defined in an .editorconfig file.

Visual Studio 2019 version: 16.5.1

Comment: I don't think that's possible with built-in configuration. One possibility would be a custom analyzer, but this is not a trivial task.

Comment: I believe you'd have to decorate each `Enum` type with the [`SuppressMessageAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Look under project properties, Build tabm enter CS1592 in the Suppress warning input. See if this helps when building the project. This means suppression not just for one place but the entire project.